# Send push notification on android and ios with Infusionsoft using php

Tags: php, android, ios, swift, infusionsoft

I am using FCM API for send push notification on android and ios

I need to pass header parameters in post method.Is it possible?

I got below error:

> Didn't run because: Unexpected HTTP response code: 401 (Unauthorized)
>   Response body: The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section "Authentication" of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.
>
> ## The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section "Authentication" of the FCM documentation, at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.
>
> ### Error 401

below is screen shot;

[image]

Comment: Please share more details about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Firebase has upgraded its server keys to a new version. Why don't you try "Legacy Server Key" for authorisation instead of server key.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MbPH.png